# App crash on Intel x86 Architecture while using OpenCV Android

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I am working with OpenCV on Android with Eclipse as an IDE.
I wish to use OpenCV's Cpp API for faster processing on Android.
For that I have converted my project to C++ nature, configured the build process to work with JNI required for using OpenCV Cpp API on Android.
I am able to run the 'OpenCV Tutorial 2 - Mixed Processing' sample example (which contains Cpp part) on my phone (Thus basic configuration is proper)

Now I made a new project in which I have C++ code. It compiles, installs and runs perfectly on ARM based phones,
but on x86 based phone (ASUS Zenphone 2) it crashes the moment execution reaches c++ code.
To be precise, app crashes when any function is called from C++ (like Canny(...) ) other statements like variable declarations don't crash the app.

Please help and thankyou in advance.

I have included x86 as ABI in Application.mk

```
/*** Application.mk ***/
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
APP_ABI := x86 armeabi-v7a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Below is the C++ code which gets called from the onFrame Method

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_javaapitest_MainActivity_processImage(JNIEnv* jobject, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray);

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_javaapitest_MainActivity_processImage(JNIEnv* jobject, jlong addrRgba, jlong addrGray,jlong addrTemp){
    Mat& rgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
    Mat& gray = *(Mat*)addrGray;
    Mat& temp = *(Mat*)addrTemp;
    RNG rng(12345);
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    /// Detect edges using canny
    /*********Crashes on below line****************/
    Canny( gray, temp, 100, 200); 
}
}
```